# get some part of image and put it back in to the main image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have 2 mins video, I seprate each 1sec of this video and change it to 120 images.
this image is too big and user can select some area of these images.I change my image matrix to to the vector and now I want to know index of the area which user selected?

after some process on that part, I want to put the changed image vector back to the main image.

I used ROI function but it didn't work, can any one help me with this problem?

Comment: So you have a frame, say `frame1` and you want to get a roi from that image, say `roi1`. You process `roi1` and put it back. Am I correct? And you will do this for each frame in the video. How does user pick the roi?

Comment: @smttsp yes exactly, user can give the coordinates by roipoly function.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have `frame1` whose dimensions are `R*C` where R and C are the number of rows and columns, respectively.

User picked a rectangle region of interest; from r1 to r2 and from c1 to c2.

```
roi1=frame1(r1:r2,c1:c2)
```

will give you the roi you want. This operation copies the region of interest to `roi1`. Then you can process this roi and copy it back to the original frame.

Another way is to play with `frame1(r1:r2,c1:c2)` which may be difficult if you are not careful and slightly slower if you are doing so many operations.

Comment: I don't get it :D , roipoly give a matrix with same dimention as main matrix but just the selected part is true I want to know what is the index of that part?

Comment: I don't know roipoly but it seems it returns a mask with zeros and ones. And you want to find corners of roi

Comment: can't I use the logic opration?

Comment: You can use it too but it will be more expensive operation. You will have to multiply the resulting matrix with roi1 using .* (dot star)